# How to prove that the Topologist's Sine Curve is a non locally compact space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $R^2$ have the Pythagorian topology. The subspace $Y=\{(0,0)\}\bigcup$ $\{(x,sin(1/x))$ |$  x>0\}$ is usually called the "*Topologist's Sine Curve*". I wish to prove that Y is a non locally compact space, but I have two questions concerning this matter:

**1.** One suggestion I got was to prove the following: *For every neighborhood $U$ (in $Y$) of $(0,0)$ there is a sequence $\{s_n\}, n\in N$ in $U$ which does not converge to any point of Cl $U$ (in Y)*. **If this is true, then $\bf(0,0)$ cannot be in the interior (in $Y$) of any compact subset of $Y$**, thus proving that $Y$ is in fact non locally compact. Why is the proposition in bold true?

**2.** How can I prove the existence of the sequence as in question 1. ?

Comment: Actually, this space is locally compact.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Could I ask you to write a proof (as an answer)? Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Oops: I just noticed that you are using a bit nonstandard definition of the topologist's sine curve. One would usually add to the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ the entire vertical interval $\{(0, y): -1\le y\le 1\}$. (As in Munkres' book.) The one you defined is indeed not locally compact, while the usual one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 1, the suggestion has an error. Instead it should say: *For every neighborhood $U$ (in $Y$) of $(0,0)$ there is a sequence $\{s_n\}, n\in N$ in $U$ which has no subsequence that converges to a point of $\text{Cl}(U)$ (in $Y$).* Also, you don't actually have to use *every* neighborhood. It would suffice to do it for all elements $U$ of a neighborhood basis of $(0,0)$, such as the intersections with $Y$ of the balls $B((0,0),r)$, $r>0$.

Regarding 2, to prove the existence of the sequence, you must write down a formula for the sequence. How do you discover the formula? The way you discover anything in mathematics: by looking at pictures, using your intuition, making intelligent guesses. Once you've written down a formula for the appropriate sequence, you prove that it has no convergent subsequence in $\text{Cl}(U)$, and you're done.